# Find the area of the minor segment.

Tags: geometry

Find the area of a minor segment formed by a circle of radius $6 cm$ and a chord whose distance from the centre of the circle is $3cm$.

I tried it in this way:

So i tried finding out $\theta$ which is $2.094$ $rad$, then I found the area using this: $\frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$, i get $37.7$ $cm^2$ but that is wrong....
what is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. For draw the chord, and join its endpoints $A$ and $B$ to the centre $O$ of the circle. Drop a perpendicular from $O$ to the midpoint $M$ of $AB$.

Then $\frac{OM}{OA}=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$, so $\angle AOM$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Double to get the angle subtended by the chord.

You had done this. But you then found the area of the **sector**, not the area of the **segment**. From the area of the sector, we need to subtract the area of a triangle with height $3$ and base $(2)(6)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: i did this....i hope you can see my answer....but the area doesn't come out! what is your area?

Comment: I have added to the post. You calculated the area of the circular sector correctly, but that is not what is asked for.

Comment: You are welcome.